# Fastest way to compute the opposite of the sign of a number in C

Tags: c, performance, bit-manipulation

We all know `sgn()` function. It can be implemented in C like something along these lines:

```
inline int sgn(int x)
{
    if(x > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(x < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Or, a more efficient, branchless version:

```
inline int sgn(int x)
{
    return (x > 0) - (x < 0);
}
```

What I want to know is the fastest method of computing the *opposite* of the sign of a given number, which can be written like this:

```
inline int asgn(int x)
{
    if(x > 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if(x < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The fastest way to do this that I know of:

```
inline int asgn(int x)
{
    return (x >> (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) | !!x;
}
```

The only flow of this approach is that it relies on the right bit shift of signed numbers being arithmetic, which, according to the standard, doesn't have to be the case. Is there a faster and/or more portable solution?

Comment: I think your asgn() function always returns 1. Did you want to write ^ 1?

Comment: @kamikaze No it doesn't. If the shift is arithmetic, the shifted number becomes -1 (all bits set), and it stays -1 after or-ing with 1.

Comment: How about `inline int asgn(int x) { return -sgn(x); }`?

Comment: @IanAbbott The answer I accepted is basically that, only written so that it's slightly more efficient.

Comment: `(x >> (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) | 1` always returns a non-zero result.  `if(x > 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if(x < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }` sometimes returns 0, so these two approaches are not equivalent.

Comment: @chux Yes, you're right, I've corrected the example. Unfortunately, the correction makes it less efficient as well. There is no possibility of `x` being zero in the place where I use this, so I didn't notice.

Comment: What makes you think that `return (x > 0) - (x < 0);` is branchless? It will possibly contain 2 branches. Just because you remove the if statement, the code doesn't automatically turn branch free.

Comment: `x >> (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) | !!x` does not fully meet the "or more portable solution" goal due to machines that use 1) non-2's complement and 2) padding with `int`.  Both these exceptions are increasingly uncommon these days.

Comment: `x >> (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1)` does not  meet the "faster" goal on many platforms today that use one cycle per shift such as found on low-end embedded processors.

Comment: @IanAbbott I think shifting negative numbers is undefined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Couldn't you just switch the order of

```
inline int sgn(int x)
{
    return (x > 0) - (x < 0);
}
```

to

```
inline int asgn(int x)
{
    return (x < 0) - (x > 0);
}
```

By the way, unless your input data is fairly random, the branchless code might be slower than the "branchy" code due to branch prediction. Best to try out both versions and see which is actually faster for you.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the simplest and fastest correct solution. I feel a bit dumb that I haven't thought of that myself.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to an unsigned int. That's well defined, if a bit counter-intuitive. Then you can access top bit without any arithmetical problems.

Two's complement is not guaranteed, but the chance of having a one's complement machine is so low it's probably not worth worrying about.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the shift on signed numbers. Indeed you cannot assume that there will be an arithmetic right-shift, while shifts on unsigned numbers are always well-defined. Something like this should be both branch-free and portable:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sgn(int x)
{
  unsigned int msb = (unsigned int)x & (1u << (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1));
  return !!x - 2*!!(int)msb;
}

int asgn(int x)
{
  unsigned int msb = (unsigned int)x & (1u << (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1));
  return 2*!!(int)msb - !!x;
}

int main(void) 
{
  printf("%d\t%d\n", sgn(-5), asgn(-5));
  printf("%d\t%d\n", sgn( 5), asgn( 5));
  printf("%d\t%d\n", sgn( 0), asgn( 0));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-1 1
1 -1
0 0
```

`msb` in this case is used as "a kind of boolean" to indicate if a number is signed or not.